# How to make more readable and shorter a karate scenario

Tags: karate

I'm new in Karate Framework. I would like to write a scenario like here:

```
version 1 :
Background:
        * url 'someURL' 
        * def user1 = {id:'123', name:'Bill'}

Given I have a user with id '123'
When I create a new user with the same id
Then I should get a response 'user with this id already exists'
```

But in Karate I have to write it like here:

```
version 2 : 
Background:
    * url 'someURL' 
    * def user1 = {id:'123', name:'Bill'}

Given request user1
When method post
Then status 201
Given path response.id
When method get
Then response == {id:'123', name:'Bill'}

    * def idUser1 = response.id

Given request == {id: idUser1, name: 'Gary'}
When method post
Then response == {code: 400, message: 'user with this id already exists'}
```

How I can get the first version with Karate framework? where I have to detail the 3 lines? ex: 
`Given I have a user with id '123'` and behind (I don't know where and how) detail it with

```
"Given request user1
When method post
Then status 201
Given path response.id
When method get"
Then response == {id:'123', name:'Bill'} etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of Karate. If you want the first version, Karate is not for you. The first version is not useful unless you *really* **really** want your product-owner or business-analyst or someone non-technical to be able to read (or even create) your tests. In my experience, this *never* happens in practice.

Even if you decide to go down path 1, you will need to write lots and lots of Java code as Cucumber "Step Definitions". Which is a waste of time, and you will lose the benefit of Karate's detailed assertions, examples of which are given below:

[image]

I have more to say on this topic, but my thoughts are explained in detail in this blog post - [Yes, Karate is not *true* BDD](https://hackernoon.com/yes-karate-is-not-true-bdd-698bf4a9be39).

All the best with whichever option you choose :)

Comment: I went through the JAVA API to run a UI related feature, but I wanted to know how to run a single scenario from the feature using this method?

Comment: Is it so hard to move a re-usable scenario into a stand-alone feature file ? I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: this I know that we can create standalone feature files for different scenario, but I was wondering how to run a single scenario out of many from within a single feature file.. I hope you get it now.

Comment: This is the wrong place to be asking this question then: https://relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/cli/run-specific-scenarios - and that may not even apply to Cucumber-JVM. All the best finding the solution.